# Working with Keras Functional API- keras.fit "No algorithm worked!"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Just getting into ML and trying to write a CNN to classify images of faces by their orientation. The codes seems to load the pictures correctly, but when it goes to fit the model, it gives the error:

> Exception has occurred: NotFoundError  No algorithm worked!    [[node
> model/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at
> c:\Users\cdues\Desktop\kerasTutorial\orentationTry.py:29) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_836]
>
> Function call stack: train_function   File
> "C:\Users\cdues\Desktop\kerasTutorial\orentationTry.py", line 29, in
>
> model.fit(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=val_it, validation_steps=8)

Below is my python (just fixed small mistake referenced in the comments):

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('firstThousandTransformed/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64)
val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('validation/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64)

imageInput = Input(shape=(128,128,1))
conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(imageInput)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
flat = Flatten()(pool2)
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(flat)
output = Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=imageInput, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=val_it, validation_steps=8)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)` there is no input called `visible` in your code ?

Comment: oops, yeah that should say imageInput, I copied the wrong version here. still, the problem persists :(

Answer (score 0):

This problem seemed to be fixed with a graphics driver update. Nice!